# xamarin forms - Default construcor not found for type

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I use the following code as a feature toggle in Xamarin.
It works fine if the page class constructor accepts no arugments, but when I need to switch on a page that accepts arguments it fails on the 2nd line  with "Default constructor not found for type..."

Is it possible to use this in any way so that I can switch to pages where constructors accept arguments?

```
var _pageString = MyNamespace.Config.AppConfig.StartUpPage;
var _page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(_pageString));
NavigationPage page = new NavigationPage(_page);
```

Here is the code where I would call the page I'm talking about

```
NavigationPage page = new NavigationPage(new SwipeCarouselLogin(_navigationService, this));
```

Comment: When you say switch what do you really mean? Are you in control of the page class? Do you know the number and kind of parameters it accepts?

Comment: You'd have to pass them into `Activator.CreateInstance`.  Or ditch that crap and use DI and config settings instead.

Comment: Based on your edit, Activator.CreateInstance has overloads to specify the parameters to the constructor in an object array. Or like @Will says, just use DI, a good container will help you resolve and wire things up as needed. Perhaps Prism of Autofac?

Comment: thanks for the inupt, I'll check it out